# combine 2 tables in acess

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, merge

hi,

i am looking for a way to combine 2 data tables into 1 in access and then filter the new table.

what i mean by combine is as follows :

table 1 :

data 1

data 2

table 2 :

data 3

data 4

new table :

data 1 data 3

data 1 data 4

data 2 data 3

data 2 data 4

i would like to have the 2 datas put in 1 line and do all the possible combinations of the 2 databases sort of like 2 for or while loop one inside the other (obviously the original databases have several fields for each data)

hope that my explanantion was understandable

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You can do it using SQL from the new database with nothing in and using `select * into [newtable] from (`  then you'd need some `union` and `subqueries` here, can you show what you've tried that hasn't worked.  Thanks.

Comment: first of all thank you for your reply
i am quite new to vba so i was trying to use a code that was given to me. this code creats an array, puts data from one query and firters it by date. i was hoping to expend on it but i am quite lost
i understand how to make a new database that would look like this (if we take the previous exemple) :
data 1 data 3
data 2 data 4
but i don't know how to make acess use multiple time the same data in one column and change it on an other column

Comment: I thought you meant database as in 3 access db's 2 existing, the 3rd new, sorry :)

Comment: yes, gustav's answer was exactly what i was looking for. 
thank you for your help in any case (i don't know how to say thank you on your comment :s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you by "database" mean table, use a Cartesian join:

```
Select 
    Table1.*, 
    Table2.*
From
    Table1, 
    Table2
```

Comment: well that was easy
thank you so much !